Strategy for maintenance large FileStream database in SQL Server
I have a document management system for my company to manage company documents(~2TB, 1.5 million+ rows in File table).
DB is SQL Server 2019. File are saved as FileStream BLOB in SQL Server. Files can be downloaded/uploaded via web frontend/API.
The DB size is roughly 2TB and 95% of those are filestream blob, with about 1% per day rate.
We have problem to backup the database. it takes too much time. and the other problem is we don't have space on raid storage.
Considering this scenario, what would be the best strategy for us regarding SQL Maintenance (backup, restore , etc.) and best use of storage space? How can we reduce the volume of database on raid storage?
Challenges we are facing:
Full Backup will take too much time.
DB Restore will take very long time if any disaster happened.
Database and Backup file size are too big and we have problem for storing them on a Raid Storage.

2TB doesn't sounds like a lot. How long is: too much time? I would say the best and cheapest strategy is to just buy some more and better hardware, since developer hours are usually far more expensive. If you use full logging, you don't need to backup complete database every day, but only from time to time, which should speed things up. Did you try running: COMPRESS on your document table? does it save any space? If yes, then perhaps you could compress the documents before storing on disk, and decompress after retrieving

To store the files in the database (filestream or blob) and keep things manageable as data volumes grow you will want to look at partitioning, filegroups, filegroup backups, and piecemeal restores.
My recommendation would be to move the files out of the database.  I wrote a blog post on my experience with this which you might find interesting.  We decided to migrate blobs out of the database for two apps a while ago - one filestream and the other in- database blob (160TB at the time.  ~1PB now out of the DB.)

1.5m company documents adding up to 20TB - for an average of 1.5MB per file - is certainly a large amount of documents.
Is there appropriate focus on the file sizes of documents being stored? For example, can high-quality colour scans be reduced to B&W fax-quality? In my experience, a readable document of dozens of pages can compress to just tens of KBs. Also can the contents of files be reduced to records of structured data, or simple text?
And what approach do you have for identifying documents that no longer need to be kept?
What is the perceived valuation of retained documents against the cost of machinery to store them and keep them all immediately online for viewing?
Do you monitor how frequently old documents are retrieved, by whom, and for what purposes?
Would it be satisfactory to move old documents onto tapes, for example, and only retrieved from the shelf by special request?
